# How to listen for multiple events

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I need to listen for 2 keyboard events on the same object ("div") like this

```js
var div = document.getElementById("div");
div.addEventListener("paste", (e) => {
  console.log(e.clipboardData.getData("text"));
});

div.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
});
```

```html
<div id="div">THE SAID DIV</div>
```

But when I do this the paste event isn't triggered

Comment: you can't paste into a `div`

Comment: but if I remove the keydown listener it works

Comment: oh, well that is interesting!

Comment: Can you show some HTML that this code goes with?

Comment: odd thing is, the keydown event doesn't fire for me in firefox - unless the div has a tabIndex

Comment: Well I can, but it's just a div, the script is for a text editor and the keydown puts each key into the div and now I want to put in a paste option

Comment: I assumed that the div is not in `contentEditable` mode. If not so please re-edit the code!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir no it's not

Comment: which browser? try other browsers, they seem to behave differently

Comment: Chrome is the only one I've tried it on

Comment: Weird! The above code snippet seems to be capturing the paste event but not the keydown event!

Comment: On which browser?

Comment: I'm on chrome by the way!

Comment: your code correctly handles paste in Firefox/Chrome/Edge - keydown is NOT handled unless the div has tabIndex attribute - but the problem you describe can not be reproduced

Comment: apollio.bitballoon.com is where the project is, if that helps

Comment: You're calling `e.preventDefault()` inside the `keydown` event listener and since the paste event (using `CTRL + V`) is really dependant of the keydown event (two actually) the paste event for the combo `CTRL + V` will be ignored as it's is the default behavior. Good work by the way, I like it. And you seem to be ignoring all the combos that could be generated using `SHIFT`, `CTRL` and `ALT`!

Comment: Thanks that fixed it :)

Comment: Marijn Haverbeke, the inventor of [**CodeMirror**](https://codemirror.net/) (the code editor used in almost every website that offers a code editting area) said that he uses a textarea element, give it the event and then get the value [of the textarea] produced by the event (keydown, paste, ...) and then use that value. Just note that CodeMirror is not using textareas at all except to get the value of such events used in editing (mainly paste)!

Comment: Here is the youtube link of the conference where he is saying the above: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UlNIb8i9j8